# 12.04 computers can't "see" each other or 10.04 computer, but not vice-versa

Tags: networking

There are three Ubuntu computers on our lan: 2 X 12.04, 1 X 10.04 and one Win XP. Each computer can ping the other.

Using Places/Network:

1) The 10.04 computer lists:

a) itself

b)Windows Networks (clicking on this shows MSHOME and Workgroup. Clicking on MSHOME, shows the Windows-only (i.e., no dual boot) computer on the network and I can log into it. Clicking on Workgroup shows the 10.04 computer [itself])

2) The first 12.04 computer (12.04-1) lists:
(for info: does not list itself)

a) the 10.04 computer

b) Windows Networks (clicking on this shows MSHOME and Workgroup:

-Clicking on MSHOME, shows the only Win computer [taking a long time to show]. This computer can sign into the Win computer.

-Clicking on Workgroup shows the 10.04 computer. Clicking on that and signing in shows the desktop of the 10.04. I can copy files from 10.04 to 12.04-1[this computer], but cannot write to 10.04)

3) The second 12.04 computer (12.04-2) lists:

(does not list itself)

a) the 10.04 computer

b) Windows Networks (clicking on this shows MSHOME and Workgroup.

-Clicking on MSHOME, shows the only Windows-only computer on the network [taking a long time to show] . This computer can sign into the Win computer and copy files from but cannot copy files to the Win

-Clicking on Workgroup shows the 10.04 computer. Clicking on that shows the desktop of the 10.04. I can copy files from 10.04 to 12.04-2[this computer], but cannot write to 10.04)

4) From inside WORKGROUP, the Win XP computer Network shows only the 10.04 computer, but not the two 12.04 computers

It appears that something needs to be enabled on the two 12.04 computers so that they are visible to each other, to the 10.04, and to the Win.

What information can I provide that will help determine the problem? (BTW, I may be just out of the newbie category, but maybe not. Please keep in mind as my experience is limited. Thanks.)

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact issue, but if you install `nmap` on the 10.04, you could run it to check the available services on the PC's. The command to run nmap is `nmap 127.0.0.1` to test the 10.04 PC and then substitute the ip address of the 12.04 machines. This will tell you what services are running on each machine.  
My guess is that you'll find SMB (SAMBA) services running on the 10.04 that aren't running the 12's.

Comment: If that's the case, install SAMBA on the 12's.

Comment: Tried to answer this timely (i.e., earlier, back when it was pertinent) but apparently I am not "qualified" to do so within 8 hours, so am doing "catch-up" now. Apology for the (externally imposed) delay. Anyway samba was the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See if SAMBA installed on the 12.04 machines. If not, install SAMBA, and configure.

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```